# Issue when percentage based layout (view equal height and width to Superview by multiplier ) for landscape mode

Tags: ios

I want to make a two view which :

**In portrait mode:**

purple one 60 % height - full width

blue one 40% height-full width to subview.

**In landscape mode :**

purple one 60 % width and full height

blue one 40 % width and full height

**HERE IS WHAT I WANT**

[image]
[image]

First I made purple one equal height to subview and multiplier by 0.6.For blue one I made equal height to subview and multiplier by 0.4.Then I added constraints 0 0 0 to purple one and 0 0 0 to blue one.So that it fits perfectly in portrait mode.

To make this in the landscape I used stack view to make vertical alignment to horizontal.It did not work.It aligned just horizontal by 60 % height of purple one and 40 % for blue one.

I did not find class size to change height and width percentage  value in landscape.

Can someone explain me how to do this ?

Thank you so  much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

[image]

I did that by using a UIStackView and switching its `.axis` between `.horizontal` and `.vertical`.

If this is iPhone-only, you can configure that change in Interface Builder:

[image]

But that won't work on iPad, since you have no size class change when we rotate; you would have to make the swap in code (in `viewWillTransition`).

Comment: Yes this is what I want. Please can you explain step by step with screen shots ?

Comment: I think you did it programatically . Is it possible to do this in Xcode ?

Comment: Well, think about how a stack view in Proportional mode works. It looks at the constraints of the views in _proportion_ to one another. So my views have intrinsic content sizes `60,60` and `40,40` respectively. In `.vertical` axis, only the heights matter, and in `.horizontal` axis, only the widths matter. So it works for both. So when you hear that we are rotating, you swap axis type.

Comment: The Axis setting can respond to size class in Interface Builder.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: Can you do gif ? Please

Comment: I understand what you mean. I know using size classes for iPad, iPhone 5 6 7 5s 4s se and iPhone 6s 7s (compact and regular) . I did not understand what you did before size classes.My problem is this.

Comment: I will be appreciated if you do gif from start to end.

Comment: I can't give 60% and 40% height and width to purple one and blue one in Stack View.

Comment: Now I understand all the things.I never used intrinsic content sizes before so I did not understand.Thank you so much !!!